# QCheckBox inside QTableWidget, clicking on label won't alter state

Tags: c++, qt

If I call `QTableWidget.setCellWidget` with a widget that contains a `QCheckBox` then clicking on the label of that checkbox will not alter the state. It appears as though the table is consuming part of the mouse events.  If I click on the box directly it will alter state. Clicking on the box or the label will cause the checkbox to get focus.

Is there anyway to get the checkbox to behave normally within the table?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a `QCheckBox` in a cell instead of setting the `Qt::ItemCheckable` flag to the item and having it behave properly?

Comment: I'm aware of that option; the cell actually contains more than just the checkbox (two of them, a lineedit and a label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a real answer but what you want seems to work in my small test program. I'll show it here in the hope it will help you:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTableWidget table(1, 1);
    QCheckBox check("Test");
    table.setCellWidget(0, 0, &check);
    table.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Maybe a checkbox directly in the cell is a special case. I have a QWidget that contains the QCheckbox - but otherwise the code is the same.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: I also tried it with a widget containing a checkbox and a label and the result was the same.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is Linux specific, are you using Windows?

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: Nope, I'm also on Linux.

Comment: Very strange, must a flag I've put on the cell or something. Thanks for confirming that it can somehow work, so I'll figure out what is the issue.